# Binary Classification with Keras on Seizure dataset

Tags: python, binary, classification, keras

At first, I´m using the Epileptic Seizure Recognition Data Set
(source: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Epileptic+Seizure+Recognition)

Hey I´m having problem to fit my model to the dataset.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy


def main():
    dataset = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
    Y = dataset["y"]
    X = dataset.drop("y", axis=1).drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
    Y = Y.values
    X = X.values

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(178, input_dim=178, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(500, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(250, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",   metrics=["accuracy"])

    model.fit(X, Y, epochs=1000, batch_size=300)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Every output looks the same as this:

```
Epoch 330/500
11500/11500 [==============================] - 0s - loss: -31.8848 - acc: 0.2000
```

So my training is not working right. What am I doing wrong? For me there further questions like:

1) How many layers do I have to add and with how many units? Is there like a rule of thumb?

2) What activation function do I have to use?

Comment: What do you mean every output looks like this? It says 330/500 every time?

Comment: no, the loss and the acc stays the same, while the data getting iterated through

Answer (score 0):

This is not a binary classification dataset. According to the dataset page,

> y contains the category of the 178-dimensional input vector. Specifically y in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

1) How many layers do I have to add and with how many units? Is there like a rule of thumb?

It depends. You have to tune both numbers for best performance. However, for a dataset with about 10k instances, I'll guess that both 8 fully connected layers and 1000 units are too much.

2) What activation function do I have to use?

ReLU is usually a good starting point for stacked `Dense` layers.

Comment: Oh well my bad, guess I will try for a multivariable classification model, thanks for the advices!